# IOS Testflight loads old code of my app even after updating to new version

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, testflight, app-store-connect

I have build an app using react-native and 
I have been uploading new builds with new version numbers to the app store and the status of the build is 'Testing'(for internal users), but when i update my app through Testflight i dont see my latest changes the version number and build number are updated but it loads very old code. This old code is 2-3 months old.
But when i run the same app on simulator or on my device(through xcode) it shows up the latest code.
Does anyone have any suggestions what i might be doing wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: check if the user that you have in Test Flight is with correct apple id which is set in your internal users.

Comment: are you trying to view your build (2)? because it says here that it is still `processing`. you have to wait a while for each bump in the build number.

Comment: @m1sh0 yes it has the correct apple id, the build 1.1.4(1) shows up in the test flight and after i update it and open the app, it opens the very old version of the app

Comment: @kenmistry no am trying to view the build  1.1.4(1)

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct group and have access to that builds. Check "All Testers" and "App Store Connect Users".

Comment: @Max i do have the access, i see the new version update on testflight. After i press on update and then open it, it still opens the very old build. Am not sure if this is the problem when react-native or xcode

Comment: Probably an issue of React-Native. If the build information are correctly displayed in TestFlight (both online and in the app, they are 100% correct) Btw you might want to check the date: Builds are only available for 89 days. After that you can no longer install them (won't update)

Comment: On TestFlight, select your app, go to `previous builds` and select the build you want to test.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem but even creating new certificates didn't help. I created a new `main.jsbundle` and that did the trick! Really difficult issue to get your head around.

Here is the exact command I used in the root of the project directory:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'
```

Comment: This worked for me, before the upload tesflight, run reset bundle

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was because of the certificate. Initially when i have uploaded the build i have generated the certificates from one laptop and then later for newer version uploads i have been trying to generate new certificates and use them from a different laptop. Once i tried to upload the new version from the initial laptop i see the latest changes on the testflight. Hope this helps someone else !

Comment: can you explain further? i am having same issue even though i am using same mac

Comment: @FH- did you ever figure this out? I am having this issue as well, very strange...